# ProGuard throws out a native class it should be able to keep

Tags: java, java-native-interface, proguard, native

A Java application using JNI is being developed. It includes the following Java class:

```
package data.jni;

import org.bytedeco.javacpp.Pointer;

@Platform(include = { "LicenseManagerNative.h" })
@Namespace("kfo")
public class LicenseManagerNative extends Pointer
{
    public LicenseManagerNative()
    {
        allocate();
    }

    private native void allocate();

    public native int checkOutLicense(String module, String version);

    public native void checkInLicense(String module);

    public native void reload();
}
```

As is apparent, this class uses `native` methods. There is also ProGuard being utilized. So far it is working using ProGuard optimization only, however an odd issue occurs when turning on ProGuard minification. On runtime I get errors such as `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: data.jni.LicenseManagerNative` which is this very class holding `native` methods.

In the ProGuard config a rule is active stating that classes including `native` functions are to be preserved by stating:

```
-keep,includedescriptorclasses class * {
    native <methods>;
}
```

When a decompiler is used on the JAR produced by ProGuard using this rule, then there is still no longer the `LicenseManagerNative` class present.

What is causing this behavior? Is the ProGuard rule defined incorrectly? Since there are `native` functions present in the class my expectation is for them to be preserved, however the class is just removed by the "minify" task of ProGuard.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to 1) Keep the class by name 2) Keep the class using `-keepclasseswithmembers`? `-keep *;` is a very broad rule; if Proguard implemented it literally, it would have to keep all your classes. And it is *not* same thing as `-keepclasseswithmembers`!

Comment: I did, this was the starting point. Initially after integrating ProGuard most classes were kept using `keep class * mypackage.**` for instance. However I do need to know why the rule above does not work as expected. There is a large number of classes to be processed correctly, so I need to rely on patterns. If I cannot do this, then trying to manually `-keep` all relevant classes one by one becomes a fool's errand. Afaik `-keep` will declare that no changes are done to the specified class at all, it seems as if `-keepclasswithmembers` only prevents renaming after minification.